# Eclipse only invoking Content Assist Auto Activation after two characters are typed

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, content-assist

At the moment I only have the setting to have it show automatically  after one character is typed, but I was wondering if there is a way to limit this to only when 2 character are typed.

As it will reduce the stalling that occurs when some single letters are typed and Eclipse loads up the list of possibilities.

So at the moment I have in **Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation**
Auto Activation triggers for Java:
.(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Note I don't want to **change the activation delay** in attempt to mimic this.

Comment: you can disable it completely , and calling it manually by using the CTLR+SPACE . other than this , i don't know.